Kubuntu Dolphin crash - X11/Wayland
I recently installed Kubuntu 24.04.1, and since then on using it I've had a number of crashes mainly relating to using Dolphin.
Without going into detail, to whom do I report these bugs, since when trying to use the bug reporter that seems buggy too, as I can only get so far, and then the 'Next' button is 'greyed out'. Just useless. Is there an actual web page for reporting these things?
Also not connected with this, I thought that Kubuntu now comes automatically installed with Wayland as graphical server, instead of Xorg. But with the command: loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID|grep Type
Type=x11.
So not Wayland, then?

Kubuntu 24.10 defaulted to Wayland as per release notes (https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-24-10-oracular-oriole-released/) but you installed the older LTS release that defaults to X.Org as documented  (Wayland was available for testing on 24.04 - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NobleNumbat/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu#Plasma_Wayland_session)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs   (You can file the report online against the package that is at fault in the crash; then use apport-collect or apport tools to add details from your box so it can be examined)
